# Understanding The Regex pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Can Anyone help me understand what the below pattern means:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]){1}([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._]){0,27}\.([a-zA-Z]){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]){1,3}/
```

What a string must have so that it bounds to the above pattern.

These preg_match patterns are so confusing to understand. !
We are using it to see that a filename conforms to above pattern.

Regards,
Sagar

Comment: Try feeding the expression to http://regex101.com — that'll get you a basic understanding.

Comment: [This visualization](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xXeDs.png) (from http://debuggex.com) might help as well.

Comment: Must start (`^`) with a single (`{1}`) alphanumeric character (`[a-zA-Z0-9]`), followed by up to 27 (`{0,27}`) further characters allowing alphanumeric, hyphen, dot or underscore (`[a-zA-Z0-9\-\._]`); a dot for the extension separator (`\.`); then an extension comprising a single (`{1}`) alpha character (`[a-zA-Z]`) and between 1 and 3 (`{1,3}`) alphanumeric characters (`[a-zA-Z0-9]`)..... it should really have a terminating `$` as well to indicate that this pattern must be a match against the entire string, not just the first part of it, otherwise `A.BC$%^&*` would match as valid

Comment: Thanks MArk :) 

You had explained it very well !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you are matching filenames that start with a `letter` or `digit`, followed by the characters `letter`, `digit`, `-`, `.`, `_`, any number of times up to 27, even 0 times. Then, there is a `.`, probably separating the extension, which is composed of a `letter` followed by the characters `letter`, `digit` any number of times from 1 to 3.

Some examples:

`a.aa`,
`0_.A0a`,
`A---____-_.a999`